# Selecting inner most element and disable click event on it in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have this hierarchy of **iframe**,

```html
<iframe>
<html>
<head><head>
<body>
  <div id="appOuterContainer">
  <form>
  <div id="appContainer">
    <div id="app">
      <div id="statusBarContainer"> <!-- status bar starts here-->
        <div id ="myStatusBar">
          <span id="one"></span>
          <span id="two">
            <a href="#">One</a>
            <a href="#" aria-popup="true">Two</a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- status bar ends here-->
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

As you can see the inner most span elements have two  elements. What I want is, I want to disable the click event only on that second anchor tag.

I have tried this:

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var obj = $(iframes).find(aria-popup="true");
$(obj).css('pointer-events','none');
```

But this doesn't work.

**EDIT:** The Html of an iframe is coming from an external source. Is it anyhow possible to achieve this?

Can anyone please help me sort out this? How can I select the inner most element of span and disable pointer event on it?

Comment: You can't specify the content of an iframe in that manner. Is the HTML in the iframe coming from an external domain? If not then just `$('#two a').css('pointer-events','none');` will work, so long as you execute it *within* the page shown in the iframe

Comment: So then how can I disable the pointer event as I specified in my question?

Comment: Yes the html in the iframe is coming from an external domain

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is not possible for security reasons. You cannot amend the content of a third party site on the client side. Imagine if it was possible; I could spoof any bank site and steal your credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it using jQuery as

```
$('a:eq(1)').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This prevents the click function to occur for the respective achor tag.

Comment: The problem is, I cannot assign the id. Because this iframe is generated from an embedded source.

Comment: I checked your edit, still not working. Well, FYI the HTML comes from OneDrive which is an external source. Is it possible to alter the HTML of an external embedded source?

Comment: Here external source refers to what? and if the code has the property `Read-only` you cannot access it.

Comment: External source means this iframe snippet is generated from OneDrive. I have taken this iframe code in my HTML page and result is the above code that I mentioned.

Comment: I see there is no Read-only attribute.

Comment: Ok, then you can access that code and btw read-only is not a an atttribute it is a property of a file .

Comment: And please give me sometime i'm working on your problem.

Comment: Sure.  Thanks. :)

Comment: So if you can assign the `id` to this code my first answer was correct.Please tell me if you can or not?

Comment: Please chech out my new answer.